# Validating form inside a modal with Vuelidate and Bootstrap Vue

Tags: validation, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

Developers,
I'm using Vuejs and I have a form inside a modal and I need to validate the form's fields on the client side using [vuelidate](https://monterail.github.io/vuelidate/).

I also use [bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/) to create the modal, but when I implement the validations I can't make the **Cancel** button clean the fields and the validations with one click. 
It closes the modal, clean the fields, but when I open it again, The fields are red showing the validation erros and I must click on **Cancel** again to cleand the validation (don't wanna do this!). My template and script are the following.

**TEMPLATE**

```
<b-modal
  id="signupFormModal"
  title="Crie a sua conta!"
  ref="modal"
  centered
  @ok="handleOk"
  @cancel="clearForm"
>
  <b-container fluid>
    <b-card>
      <b-form @submit.stop.prevent="handleSubmit">
        <b-form-group
          id="email"
          label-for="email"
        >
          <b-form-input
            ref="focusElement"
            autocomplete="username"
            id="email"
            type="email"
            v-model.trim="form.email"
            :state="$v.form.email.$dirty ? !$v.form.email.$error : null"
            @input="$v.form.email.$touch()"
            required
            placeholder="E-mail"
          />
        <small class="error">{{emailErrors}}</small>
        </b-form-group>
      </b-form>
    </b-card>
  </b-container>
</b-modal>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
import { required, minLength, sameAs, email } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'

export default {  
name: 'myForm',
  data: () => ({
    form: {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      confirmPassword: ''
    },
    show: true,
    nameState: null
  }),
  validations: {
    form: {
      email: { required, email },
      password: {
        required,
        minLength: minLength(6)
      },
      confirmPassword: {
        required,
        sameAsPassword: sameAs('password')
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
emailErrors () {
  if (!this.$v.form.email.$dirty) {
    this.returnNull()
    return ''
  } else if (!this.$v.form.email.required) {
    this.returnFalse()
    return 'E-mail é obrigatório'
  } else if (!this.$v.form.email.email) {
    this.returnFalse()
    return 'Exemplo: exemplo@exemplo.com'
  } else {
    this.returnNull()
  }
}
  },

methods: {
    clearForm () {
      /* Reset our form values */
      this.form.email = ''
      this.form.password = ''
      this.form.confirmPassword = ''
      this.$v.$reset()
    },
handleOk (evt) {
  // Prevent modal from closing
  evt.preventDefault()
  if (!this.$v.invalid) {
    this.handleSubmit()
  } else {
    this.$v.touch()
  }
},

handleSubmit () {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.form))
  this.clearForm()
  this.$refs.modal.hide()
},

focusMyElement (e) {
  this.$refs.focusElement.focus()
},

returnNull () {
  this.nameState = null
},
returnFalse () {
  this.nameState = false
},
returnTrue () {
  this.nameState = null
}
  }
}
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this issue? I'm on this dilema for 2 days now.

Appreciate the help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In your *clearForm* method just replace the call to *$reset()* by:

```
this.$nextTick(() => { this.$v.$reset(); })
```

There some cases when you need to call *$reset()* after the DOM has been updated and the data changed, and this is achieved with *[nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick)*